# What does Griffith mean by adding a prime on integration variables?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, notation, integration

In the book "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by Griffith, the author mentions electric potential as a point function writes the equation for electric potential as

[image]

Then in a side note he write "To avoid any possible ambiguity, I should perhaps put a prime on the integration variable"

[image]

To what 'ambiguity' is he refering to and what how does adding the prime clarify it?

Comment: The electric field in the integral is a function of the radius, which is typically denoted by $r$. To avoid confusing the independent variable in the integrand with the upper bound of the integral (which corresponds to the radius in the potential function on the left) he suggests distinguishing them with a prime. Is that clear?

Answer (score 3):

The primed coordinate is what you are integrating over, whereas the unprimed coordinate is the point in space you are computing the potential for. If $r$ was left unprimed in $E(r)$ it could be seen as ambiguous whether we are talking about the variable of integration or not.

Comment: Does 'dl' require a prime too? As dl and dl' would mean the same when we integrate over a given curve in the field.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about integrals, the variable of integration is "dummy", in the following sense. Suppose $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is a function, then for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=\int_0^xf(s)\,ds=\int_0^xf(\xi)\,d\xi=\int_0^xf(\ddot{\smile})\,d \ddot{\smile}=\int_0^xf(@)\,d@=\int_0^xf(\sharp)\,d\sharp,
\end{align}
and so on. The actual symbol used does not matter except for $x$: what is completely nonsense notation is
\begin{align}
\int_0^xf(x)\,dx,
\end{align}
because the $x$ is being used in two places with different meanings, so it's just confusing and wrong. We can keep going: if you want, you can write
\begin{align}
\int_0^xf(y)\,dy= \int_0^xf(x')\,dx'=\int_0^{x}f(\tilde{x})\,d\tilde{x}.
\end{align}
Literally, any other symbol than $x$ can be used as the integration symbol. Same thing with line integrals